# Getting started with a facebook application

Tags: facebook

I'm really new to Facebook application development, and I'm quite confused about application permissions and why the php sdk is so limiting and has so few precoded functions.

First off, how do I check if a user has set proper permissions for my application, and if not, display that standard dialog immediately instead of using FBML and making them click the link?

Secondly, how do I publish to a user's stream with the php apis?

Finally, are there any good tutorial sites for making a php based canvas application that use the latest versions of all the sdks?

Thank you for your help! I really don't see why so much of this is Javascript, it would really make much more sense to me to have things like: `if(!$facebook->appHasPerm('publish_stream'){$facebook->showPermDialog('publish_stream');}`

I'd feel like I have much more control over the application if it worked like that.

Comment: I really have the distinct feeling I'm missing something incredibly obvious here.

Comment: Now I do agree that FB documentation is the worst, and their APIs are far from being perfect or complete..but your thinking also doesn't make sense, client-side interactions needs client-side technology..how do you want to trigger a `showPermDialog` from server side language? :-)

Comment: @ifaour Well wouldn't that really be up to Facebook? It'd exit the script execution with `die` and invoke some api call on their side to direct the user to the proper page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started with fb apps a week ago and the best and most helpfull guide I found was this one:

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development/

You can also find a great login function in the fbmain.php of that guide.

-michael

Comment: If you want to work without FBML you have to create the dialog on your own and use php like `$facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',array('message' => 'your message'));` to submit them.

Comment: Is there any way to render FBML within the iframe? I had a previous simple UI set up already, but that broke with the iframe option. I'm working on JQuery but it'd be way easier if I could use the official facebook stuff.

Comment: Yes that is possible just check the invite.php of the Guide for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code for the authentication.

```
<?php 
$app_id = 'API_ID';
$app_sec = 'SECRETE';
$canvas_page = 'CANVAS_URL';
$scope = '&scope=user_photos,email,publish_stream';
$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page).$scope;
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
if (empty($data["user_id"])) {  
echo("<fb:redirect url='".$auth_url."' />");
}
$access_token = $data['oauth_token'];
$user_id = $data["user_id"];
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents(
'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' .
$access_token));
function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $application_secret) {
$args = array();
parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
ksort($args);
$payload = '';
foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
if ($key != 'sig') {
  $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
}
}
if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args['sig']) {
return null;
}
return $args;
}
$cookie = get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_sec);
//facebook application
//set facebook application id, secret key and api key here
$fbconfig['appid' ] = "APP_ID";
$fbconfig['api'   ] = "API";
$fbconfig['secret'] = "SECRETE";
//set application urls here
$fbconfig['baseUrl']    =   "BASE_URL";
$fbconfig['appBaseUrl'] =   "APP_BASE_URL";
$uid=   null; //facebook user id
try{
require_once "facebook.php";
}
catch(Exception $o){
 echo '<pre>';
print_r($o);
echo '</pre>';
}
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
 ));
?>
```

To publish to the wall

```
require_once 'authentication.php';
require_once "facebook.php";
$attachment = array('message' => 'some message',
                    'name' => 'name',
                    'caption' => "caption",
                    'link' => 'http://example.com/',
                    'description' => 'description',
                    'actions' => array(array('name' => 'name', 'link' =>       'http://example.com/')) );
 $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed?access_token='.$access_token, 'post', $attachment);
```